# How can I migrate from GitHub to VSTS with the same Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our team is trying to migrate from GitHub environment to Microsoft Visual Studio Team Service environment. However, the GitHub already has a Jenkins pipeline.

I want to use the same pipeline but move it to the VSTS environment.

There are no clear tutorials regarding this issue.

I want to keep the same configuration but make this work for the repository in VSTS Git.

Please help.

Comment: Is it possible for you to config a new jenkins job, and only change the source code managment with VSTS git repo and keep others same as your current jenkins job?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [service hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/jenkins?view=vsts) for Jenkins. That will allow you to trigger Jenkins builds as appropriate.